# Mailchimp api integration in php

Tags: api, mailchimp

I want to update mailchimp campaign html i want to use this API https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/campaign-content/set-campaign-content/
but I am confusing how to add data in [] in
$response = $client->campaigns->setContent("campaign_id", []);

Comment: Are you using Mailchimp SDK?

Comment: yes i installed composer and include autload.php file.

Comment: require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
$mailchimp = new \MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient();

$mailchimp->setConfig([
 'apiKey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us1',
 'server' => 'us1'
]);

 $html = '<div style="background:red; color:#fff; padding:50px">Hello World</div>';
    $response = $mailchimp->campaigns->setContent("f79aeaea60",[
      'template' => ['id' => 47615, 
        'sections' => ['body' => $html]
        ]);
print_r($response);

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't use Mailchimp SDK, but I prefer to use my own function. It's very simple:

```
<?php

$content = 'This is a test';

// STEP #1: CREATING CAMPAIGN
$url = 'https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns';
$method = 'post';
$data = ['type' => 'regular', 'recipients' => ['list_id' => '***'], 'settings' => ['subject_line' => 'Test', 'title' => 'Test', 'from_name' => '***', 'reply_to' => '***@***', 'folder_id' => '***']];
$campaign = MC($url, $method, $data);

// STEP #2: ADDING CONTENT TO CAMPAIGN
$url = "https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/$campaign/content";
$method = 'put';
$data = ['template' => ['id' => ***, 'sections' => ['content' => $content]]]; // Here I'm using a template: 'content' is a placeholder in my template (see MC Documentation)
MC($url, $method, $data);

function MC($url, $method, $data) {
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Authorization: ***', 'Content-Type: application/json'], // *** = apiKey
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30
]);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($method === 'post') return json_decode($response)->id;
}
```

**Replace *** with your data.**

That's it.

It works for me. Let me know if it works for you as well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this looks good, but every time it through error API key is invalid i used in this way Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us1 and with without space Authorization:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us1 please help.

Comment: {"type":"https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/errors/","title":"API Key Invalid","status":401,"detail":"Your request did not include an API key.","instance":"383c5a86-03ee-8dfd-00e4-6ed665a500d8"}

Comment: @Farhan Haider Try `Authorization: Basic ***` (where *** is your apiKey). Leave a space between `Basic` and apiKey.

Comment: Now i am getting this response.{"type":"https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/errors/","title":"Method Not Allowed","status":405,"detail":"The requested method and resource are not compatible. See the Allow header for this resource's available methods.","instance":"b116d076-fed3-569d-1526-afb2136627c3"}

Comment: @Farhan Haider Strange, that code works perfectly for me. See here for more info about 405 error: https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/errors Try the #1 step only and see what happens. Check your MC account to see if something has been created. Also, read MC documentation about API.